# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\alpha$, show $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_1x_2\dots x_n)^{1/n} =\alpha$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \alpha$ and $x_n \gt 0$ for all $n$,
show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_1x_2\dots x_n)^{1/n} = \alpha.$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** take log both sides and use the well-known theorem of Cesaro stating that: if x(n)'s are

positive real numbers such that lim x(n) = a, then lim (x(1) +..+ x(n))/n = a.

Comment: What is x(n)? The question has $x_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $b_n = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$. Since $(b_n)$ is sequence of positive  real numbers we know that if the limit of $(b_{n+1}/b_n)$ exist then this is equal to the limit $b_n^{1/n}$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (b_{n+1}/b_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty}  x_{n+1}= \alpha$$ Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}  b_n^{1/n}= \alpha$, as desired.

Comment: And you provide an interesting proof of the equivalence between the root test and the ratio test using Stolz Cesaro. =)